# Java Regex - Finding specific string within a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match a string that start with the set word "hotel", then a hyphen, then a word of any length, then another hyphen and finally a number of any length.

**Edit:** Dima gave the solution I needed in the comments of this question! Thanks Dima.

**Further edit:** elaborating on Dima's answer, adding capturing groups making it easier to retrieve the information entered, and correcting the last bit to only accept digits:

`^hotel-(.+)-(\d+)`

Comment: What is wrong with "hotel-something"? Why is that not good?

Comment: This maybe: `^hotel-.+-.+` or equivalently `^hotel(-.+){2,}

Comment: Please keep the original question, so it can be useful for others.

Comment: Woops I didn't mean to delete the whole question, I was trying to make it more concise

Answer (score 2):

```
^hotel-(.)*$
```

(But hotel-something WILL work, according to your initial statement).

So, if you actually want something like:

```
hotel-XXXXXX-YYYYYYY
```

Then the regex is :

```
^hotel-(.)*-(.)*$
```

Try a regex online tester like http://www.regextester.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the start of the input, you use `^`.

so if you have `^hotel-\b`, that will force `hotel` to be at the start of the string.

as a note, you can use `$` for the end of the string in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

```
\bhotel-[^\s-]+-[^\s-]+\b
```

`\b` means that it should be a word boundery

`[^\s-]` means anything but `-` or whitespace

https://regex101.com/r/mH3vY8/1